# How do I create an internal Layer 4 load balancer in Kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create an internal (no external IP) layer 4 load balancer in AWS - either a Network LB or Classic LB - for internal traffic management instead of using the kube-proxy.

Below is my manifest file - it keeps creating an external LB regardless of how I specify the annotations. I have tried this without the "aws-load-balancer-type" annotation as well as the "aws-load-balancer-scheme", which is supposed to default to "internal". I am not sure what to try next. (I will probably try a layer 7 LB next.)

```
% k get svc|grep test
test-internal-lb                      LoadBalancer   10.100.253.178   a29xxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com    80:xxx/TCP,443:xxx/TCP   8s
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-internal-lb
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb-ip
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: test-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: It looks like this cannot be done within Kubernetes. I know I can create an internal NLB or CLB with the AWS CLI or console and set up the correct configs and tags, but every document I have found is outdated. Setting "aws-load-balancer-scheme" to "internal" does not work, nor do other configurations. They all create external LBs.

Comment: i also looking for a fix. I need to create Private Load balancer service for my pods and service is will front with api gateway. This api gateway will have Public IP exposed.

Comment: @knowdotnet I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

```
test-app            LoadBalancer   172.20.40.154    internal-a03xxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com   80:8000/TCP   11d
```

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: “true”
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  selector:
    app: test-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000
```